# WooCommerce variation sorting in Admin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Products with long lists (100+) of variations are difficult to organize into groups. By default we have a drag and drop option but there must be a better way. I've searched for some time now, this code seems to be on the right track:

```
function ibx_woocommerce_sort_variation(){
if($query->is_admin) {

    if ($query->get('post_type') == 'product_variation')
    {
      $query->set('orderby', 'id');
      $query->set('order', 'ASC');
    }
}
return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','ibx_woocommerce_sort_variation');
```

But it doesn't work, no sorting happens in admin nor plugins that parse the variations.

Comment: As it is a "menu" where you can reorder the variations and affect the "menu_order", you can not change the display order by ID or whatever else… It will be always ordered by "menu_order".

Comment: Is menu_order editable by any other means?